# CKEditor not respecting max image dimensions, alternatives?

Tags: input-formats, 10

Even though maximum image dimensions have been set, my users are still uploading massive images using CKEDITOR. this seems to be a [known issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3373793) with no stable patch.

What are good alternatives to allow users to embed images (with limits on dimensions) directly into CKEDITOR?

[image: Screenshot from admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html]

Comment: Does setting a maximum file size to something like 5 MB work around the problem to a small extent?

Comment: Did you try any of the patches in the issue and the duplicate issue?